# C++: One client communicating with multiple server

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, client-server

I was wondering, if it is possible to let one client communicate with multiple server at the same time. As far as I know, common browsers like for example firefox are doing exactly this.

The problem I have now is, that the client has to listen and wait for data from the server, rather then requesting it itself. It has to listen to multiple server at once. Is this even possible? What happens if the client is listening to server 1 and server 2 sends something? Is the package lost or will it be resend until the client communicates a successful receival? The protocol used is TCP.

edit: platform is Windows. Thanks for pointing this out Arunmu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing different from regular socket programming using select/poll/epoll OR using thread-pool OR using process-per-connection OR whatever model that you know. 
I can show you a rough pseudo-code on how to do it with epoll.
NOTE: None of my functions exist in C++, its just for explanation purpose. ANd I am ALSO assuming that you are on Linux, since you have mentioned nothing about the platform.

```
socket sd = connect("server.com", 8080);
sd.set_nonblocking(1);
epoll_event event;
event.data.fd = sd
epoll_ctl(ADD, event);
...
...
while (True) {
  auto n = epoll_wait(events, 1);
  for (int i : 1...n) {
    if (events[i].data.fd == sd) // The socket added in epoll_ctl
    {
      std::thread(&Session::read_handler, rd_hndler_, sd); // Call the read in another thread or same thread
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you got the gist. In essence, think of server like a client and client like a server and you have your problem solved (kind of). Check out below link to know more about epoll 
https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/

To see an fully functional server design using epoll, checkout: 
https://github.com/arun11299/cpp-reactor-server/blob/master/epoll/reactor.cc

Comment: @YokeM Glad to help.